# What is the meaning of まさか...お前が ...喜べ

Tags: grammar, word-choice, imperatives

I read in a manga that a character said "...まさか...お前が", "...喜べ" does it make sense to add imperative form here or the 喜べ isn't connected to the omae ga

Comment: More context would be appreciated. For example, are the 「まさか」、「お前が」、and 「喜べ」 all part of the same speech bubble? Who is the character speaking to? What are the characters talking about? etc.

Comment: All the three are spoken in different speech bubbles and the character is talking first about the who the person became with hasitation and then says masaka.. omaega...  he pauses and then goes on to say  yorokobe ( the next speech bubble isすべてお前らの思い通りだ) i don't know if they are all comnected or if he cut himself off after omaega and changed the subject

Comment: From that context, I imagine that person A is saying something like, "So you're the one who was behind this all along. Are you happy now, now that everything went as you planned?" Is that close?

Comment: So it makes sense to say" omae ga yorokobe"? I thought it was seperated, he knew that he was the one behind

Comment: In manga, half of the information is acquired through the drawings (and the other half through the text).  If you can't tell what those mean when you have access to all of the drawings, you surely couldn't expect us to decipher them without the drawings, either.

Comment: What is the meaning wasn't my original question it's been edited not by me.. i just don't know how the imperative form is used  and if it make sense  to say omae ga (three dots)  yorokobe because it's commanding

Answer (score 3):

Assuming from comments that speaker is saying something like

> So you're the one who was behind this all along. Are you happy now,
>   now that everything went as you planned?

Here's the breakdown

**まさか...** - No way.../I never would have thought...

**お前が（黒幕だったんだ）...** - You're the one (who was behind this all along)...

**（お前が）喜べ...すべてお前らの思い通りだ** - (Sarcastically, in admission of defeat) Rejoice. Everything went exactly as you planned.